# Icon displayed wrongly in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Im using daterangepicker in my project, and it show nicely in chrome, but in IE it show different.

In chrome:

[image]

In IE:

[image]

Anyone know why is it like that and how to solve that?

Comment: I've tried the sample in this link(http://www.daterangepicker.com/) and run it in IE. And it works well in IE9-11(this version of script do not support IE version older than 9).therunning result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTQZt.jpg
I would like to know that what is your IE's version and the daterangepicker library you've referred to. This may be easier to help you solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is for a version of IE that doesn't support the css rotation that the library is using in its stylesheet, as it looks as if the chevrons are created in css.

I'd try update the css so it uses a [2D rotation](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_transform.asp) (and possibly you'll also need the `-ms-` prefix). If you're still supporting <IE8 then you should either look for a polyfill, change the way the chevrons are rendered (if possible), and then if all else fails, question if you really need to support <IE8 in 2018.